# How do you call parent object functions from child objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, extend

So, I was reading up on John Resig's [blog](http://ejohn.org/), saw his [micro-templating javascript engine](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) and decided to try and implement my own template management system for javascript, to deepen my understanding of prototype inheritance. However, the minute I started writing it, I ran into a problem.

To start off, here is my base code:

```
function template_manager() { };

template_manager.prototype = {
    tags: {},
    templates: {},
    output: {},
    default_template: "default",
    set: function (tags, template_name) {
        template_name = "Greetings!";
        //template_name = this._util.template(this.nothing, this.default_template);
        console.log(template_name);
    },
    get: function(tags, template_name) {
        console.log("Getting");
    },
    unset: function(tags, template_name) {
        console.log("Removing");
    },
    render: function(template_name) {
        console.log("Rendering");
    },
    //_util goes here
};

// Take it for a quick test drive.
test = new template_manager;
test.set();
test.get();
test.unset();
test.render();
```

Then I started working on some common code, and I decided to put it into a utility object:

```
    _util: {
        // Used to set the default values for optional arguments
        optional: function(obj, def_value) {
            return (typeof obj === "nothing") ? obj : def_value;
        },
        template: function(template_name) {
            return this._util.optional(template_name, this.default_template);
        },
    },
```

And now, when I try to call my `_util.template()` function in my `set()` function I of course get an error because `this` points to the `_util` object rather than the `template_manager` object. I've take a look at the jQuery `extend` method, and I think that I understand what it's doing.  My question is, do I **need** to implement my own / use jQuery's `extend` method, or is there another way for me to call the `template_manager` object from my `_util` object?

(P. S. I've looked at Douglas Crockford's [article](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) on prototype inheritance, and I **think** the answer is there, but I'm afraid I don't fully understand it yet.)

Comment: @Chris, serves me right for not double checking.  Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `call` or `apply` i.e.

```
template_manager.prototype = {
    set: function (tags, template_name) {
        template_name = "Greetings!";
        template_name = this._util.optional.call(this, this.nothing, this.default_template);
        console.log(template_name);
    }
}
```

See ["Getting Out of Binding Situations in JavaScript"](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/getoutbindingsituations/) article for more explicit explanation.

Comment: The solution works and the article does an excellent job explaining the scope in more detail.  Thank you very much Li0liQ!